# Socket.io sending message to specific user

Tags: php, web-applications, socket.io, xampp, laravel-8

Scenario: Three users are connected to chat application and want to chat to each other using socket.io for chat message

Problem:
My problem is that when the user1 chats to user2 the message from user1 does reach to user2 but the messages are also displayed on chat dialog of jquery of user3. My idea was to use the socket.id but I used it but no success I also tried using broadcast, to, in and also room.

On client side I am appending the message to id but the message are also viewed by other users that the problem

Any help for this problem

server.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express () ;
const server=require('http').createServer(app) ;
const io=require ('socket.io')(server, {
        cors:{ 
                origin: '*'
        }
 }) ;
 var user={};
  

  io.on('connection').(socket)=>{

       console.log('Connected');

       socket.on('UserConnected' , (data) =>{
            user['data.username']=socket.id;
            socket.join('room');
             console.log(user['data.username']) ;
       }) ;


      socket.on('ChatWith' , (data) => {
        user['ChatWith']=data.id;
        console.log(user['ChatWith']) ;

       }) ;


       socket.io('SingleChatMessage' , (data) => {

                  io.sockets.to('room').to(user['data.username']). emit('ReceivedSingleChatMessage',{username: data.username, message: message, user_id: user['ChatWith']}) ;

  }) ;

   socket.on('disconnect' , (socket) =>{
         console. log('Disconnected');
   }) ;


       

  }) ;
```

Laravel 8 : View. Blade.php

```
$(function() {
      let ip_address='127.0.0.1';
      let socket_port='3306';
      let socket=io(ip_address + ':' + socket_port) ;
       
       socket.on('connection') ;
        
       var socketID=socket.id;
        var id='<?php   echo Session::get('username')? >';
         socket.io('UserConnected', {socketID : socketID, id1: id1 }) ;

        $('#SendSocket').click(function() {
              var username= document.getElementById('username').innerHTML;
             var sender='<?php echo Session:get('username') ; ? >;
             var message=document.getElementById ('message'). value;
            socket.emit('SingleChatMessage', {sender: sender, username:username, message:message}) ;

          document.getElementById ('message'). value=' ';

        }) ;

       socket.on('ReceivedSingleChatMessage', (data)  =>{
         $('.chat-content ul').append('<li><b>\
             + data.username + '</b>: ' + data.message + '</li>') ;  

    }) ;




  }) ;
```

Laravel 8 View Id

```
<div class='chat-content' style='height : 500px;'>
    <ul style='list-style: none;'>

    </ul>
</div>



 <textarea placeholder='Type' id='message' ></textarea>
```

Comment: If you want us to help you debug your problem with the data going to the wrong user you'll need to show your code and provide some sample data. We can't guess the problem just from a fairly brief description. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code which I am facing the problem @ADyson

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You seem to be broadcasting every message to the whole room, and it looks like there is only one room containing all users. Instead, just send the message to the specific intended user.

Comment: You got my problem but My question is like how to send to specific user

Comment: how to send to only specified user using like what . Because I am new to socket.io

Comment: @Adyson Any help?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with socket.io either, but it seems like this would be a common requirement and there would be plenty of information about it already online. I suggest you [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=socket+io+send+to+specific+user)...did you do any research of your own once I made the suggestion? I guess not, given the speed at which you responded.

Comment: I looked to the online tutorial of sending chat message using socket.io but they only send messages from one to second without showing or telling how to avoid the message viewed by the third user . My Code works same but when I open my chat dialog to chat with another user the same chats can be viewed when chats with previous user

Comment: ok well use the link I provided to find other resources which do discuss it. Just because one tutorial doesn't mention it doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: @Adyson the error is when I chat with another user the same chats are viewed and the user3 can chat with same chats appended. I tried to save their socket.id with their username in dict so when I send the chats to specified user the same chats can be send to specified user but problem remains the same

Comment: Yes I understand the problem, you've already explained that. Instead of repeating yourself, go and use the resources I've provided to try and solve your problem. There are lots of useful possibilities.

Comment: And also make sure you remove the code which sends the message to the whole room.